# How to access the names of the category name in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, slug

I'm trying to get the category name via the_slug() but I can't get it displayed via several methods. Does anyone know what's the right term?

Comment: In which context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have the slug but want to get the name?

```
$_cat = get_category_by_slug('category-slug'); // Returns Category Object
$_category_name = $_cat->name;
```

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug)

Answer (score 4):

You should use [get_term_by](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by). Example:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
echo $term->name;
```

Comment: actually i realised that i was a little confused. i realised that what i have now is a custom taxonomy called portfolio_catogories. and in my portfolio_categories, i have several categories. as i'm trying to make a filter work, i need to get the names of these categories, most likely via slugs

Comment: may i know what kind does $value holds? I've read the get_term_by codex but i'm still unsure what value to give it

Comment: The `$value` is your term slug in this case. If you search by name then it will be the term name.